# Mysql GROUP BY clause not behaving well with between function in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have these two identical statements. THe first one works but the second is not working or that it is taking a disproportionate amount of time that I cannot wait for it

statemant 1

```
select * from wtl where id between 1 and 500000
group by a_num,b_num,calldate,call_time,duration
```

statement 2

```
select * from wtl where id between 500001 and 1000000
group by a_num,b_num,calldate,call_time,duration
```

The first statement starts returning result sets withing seconds while the second did not return anything for over 30 minutes

both statements are supposed to process 500000 records. id is the primary key

Comment: All bets are off when you use group by without aggregate functions.

Comment: You didn't profile the query. You're processing 500 THOUSAND records and returning them - that action itself takes time to send data through network and to receive it on the other end on top of finding it. You're also grouping the records without using aggregate functions and you have multiple criteria. On top of it, you didn't try to profile the query at all - MySQL provides detailed query profile information, next to `EXPLAIN` plan - `SET PROFILING = 1; SELECT... rest of your query; SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1; SET PROFILING = 0;`. You can see, in detail, every step that happens and time taken.

Comment: Thanks for your reply especially on the query profile info. because I have not been using that feature. My sever is on my laptop and not over a network. I later discover that it was actually processing my query, I only needed to allow it more time. I also oberved that  it returned faster when there are duplicates and that accounted for the statement1 returning faster than statement2 but the difference in time is baffling. All I am trying to do is to eliminate duplicates by writing the result set to another table. Thank you very much for helping me